# Downloaded selenium binding with java. antivirus shows malicious file in it (heur_java.re0)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ide

Downloaded selenium binding with java. antivirus shows the malicious file in it (heur_java.re0)
Don't know if it's safe to upload the whole package to my ide.
Can't figure out which file is affected.

Does someone know anything about it?

Appreciate!

Comment: I don’t know what the Selenium binding with Java is - Selenium _is_ Java! I suspect you might have downloaded something dodgy as it doesn’t sound like a legitimate item.

Comment: @BoristheSpider if you go to selenium.dev/downloads/ (which is a legitimate website) there are selenium clients and Webdriver language bindings. And the JAVA package has a virus in it! I deleted the jar that had it, but still suspicious.